# Does WP create multiple images?

Tags: images

When uploading an image in WP, does it creating multiple sizes (and multiple files) of the image?

If so, are they all loaded or just certain ones (which and why)?  Meaning, if x images are created from one uploaded, which one does WP show?

Why does it need multiple images anyways if you aren't using a responsive web design?

Comment: The answer to your first question is **yes**. For the second question: can you please elaborate/clarify what you mean?

Comment: @ChipBennett: I've edited the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WordPress shows whichever image is requested by the function that outputs those images in the template. The presentation of images is entirely up to the theme developer, WordPress doesn't make this decision on its own.

For example, [`the_post_thumbnail`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) function:

```
the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');       // Thumbnail (default 150px x 150px max)
the_post_thumbnail('medium');          // Medium resolution (default 300px x 300px max)
the_post_thumbnail('large');           // Large resolution (default 640px x 640px max)
the_post_thumbnail('full');            // Full resolution (original size uploaded)
```

In addition to the default sizes, theme and plugin developers can add their own custom sizes via [`add_image_size`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size). An example use case for this is a header banner, where you need a specific cropped image size.

Why it does this is for flexibility and efficiency on the front end. Consider the case of a gallery of thumbnails where the originals are all 1200px + images. Simply scaling the full size images to thumbnail size may result in a 20mb page load, versus a 2mb page load if resized thumbnails are displayed.